# Edit file scanner to scan only first .01MB of each file

Tags: c, file-io, entropy

This program http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/ scans an entire file to determine it's information density (aka entropy/randomness).

I want to edit it to scan only the first .01 MB of the file rather than the whole thing in order to speed up scan times (the network share I need to scan is 2TB).

The source is included in the download so it should be easy to do; I'm just not sure how to get started.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the code in ent.c, shows a while statement on line 181.  This line does an fgetc from the file pointed to by fp.  In order to get this to work correctly, you would just add a counter to the statement.  Something along the lines of

```
while ((my_count++ < MAX_COUNT) && ((oc = fgetc(fp)) != EOF))
```

where my_count is an int (or long - depending on how big you really want) and MAX_COUNT for you would be 100000.  Be sure to initialize my_count to 0.

Comment: Did you mean line 181?

Comment: I made the edit, but it doesn't seem to have affected the scan time like I had hoped.  For example, a small .txt file scans very fast, but a large .iso file takes awhile. This is what my code looks like:

/* Scan input file and count character occurrences */
 float my_count = 0;
 const MAX_COUNT = 100000;
 while ((my_count++ < MAX_COUNT) && ((oc = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)


Any ideas how to proceed in speeding up the scan time?

Comment: .iso files are binary and can have huge lines.  I would look at the length of the return from fgetc.  Also, try doing just 1 line, then 2 lines, 4 lines, 8 lines, ... to see where it goes long.  Let me know how this works out.

Comment: What is MAX_COUNT referring to exactly?  I was under the impression we were limiting the number of bits/bytes that would be scanned.  If this is the case, it doesn't seem like it would matter how long the "lines" are.

For example, I would expect it to simply extract and scan only the first .01MB of each file regardless of line length.

How do I do just 1 line, 2 lines, etc., and how is this different from setting MAX_COUNT to 100000?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ahh I see.  It doesn't seem like line counting would be the best way to limit the scan size to .01MB then (since, as you said, some filetypes might have longer lines than others).

Do you know of a way to limit it to .01MB exactly?

Comment: After relooking at your comment, I see that it is fgetc, not fgets.  My mistake.  You should already be reading the correct number of characters via my initial suggestion.  One thing to look at is to print out a '.' every 1000 characters.  Do they come out in a smooth progression or is it choppy?  That should give you a clue.  Let me know.

Comment: Let's back up a bit, since I think I might be misunderstanding.  I implemented your suggestion by adding the counter.  I thought this would make every file scan in the same amount of time (since we are only scanning the first .01MB).  But this doesn't seem to be the case. Is your suggestion supposed to limit the scan size to .01MB, or just limit the number of lines read? The latter might not be sufficient, because as you said, different file types have different line lengths. Was there anything else I needed to do besides adding the counter?

Comment: After running more tests, it doesn't seem like adding the counter changes the behavior of the program at all. Is there anything else we need to do?

Comment: Ahhh...just kidding!  I thought ent.exe was simply calling ent.c; however, it appears ent.c is actually compiled into the .exe.  I compiled it and the .iso file scans very fast.  Now, I just need to run some more tests to make sure scanning only .01MB yields correct results for the information density.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are all good, a check mark would be appreciated.  Good luck and let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I added the check mark for you.  However, I do have another question:

Would it be possible to start scanning, for example, 20 lines into the file?  How would I edit the scanner to do that?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Before the while loop, you should just do another while loop looking for the cc = '\n'.  Count however many of these you want.  You need to be careful that there are at least that many lines in the file so that you don't have to do error recovery.